# Javascript - get milliseconds from float seconds

Tags: javascript

I got a string that represents seconds (e.g value is "14.76580").
I want to set a new variable that has the value of the decimal portion (milliseconds) of that string ( e.g x = 76580 ) and I'm not sure what's the best way to do that.
May you help please ?

Comment: How many decimals do you want to move to before the decimal point?

Comment: That's 765.8, not 76580 milliseconds. What do you really want?

Comment: And where is your code..?

Comment: At this point, the accepted answer doesn't seem to be correct; it doesn't return the milliseconds portion of the given time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the decimal part from that string pattern . You can use [string.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function of Javascript.

*Splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.*

So ,

```
// splits the string into two elements "14" and "76580"    
var arr = "14.76580".split("."); 
// gives the decimal part
var x = arr[1];
// convert it to Integer
var y = parseInt(x,10);
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `parseInt` to make it as integer

Comment: Point taken , didn't posted it as the OP didn't say he want to convert it to `int`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this function to calculate the ms portion from a time (works on strings too):

```
function getMilliSeconds(num)
{
    return (num % 1) * 1000;
}

getMilliSeconds(1.123); // 123
getMilliSeconds(14.76580); // 765.8000000000005
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the existing answers, you can also use a bit of arithmetic:

```
var a = parseFloat(14.76580);//get the number as a float
var b = Math.floor(a);//get the whole part
var c = a-b;//get the decimal part by substracting the whole part from the full float value
```

Since JS is so permissive, even this would work:

```
var value = "14.76580";
var decimal = value-parseInt(value);
```